Create a long format summary
How could I convert a wide table to long format using a formula in Google Sheets? Within each group, the values should be alphabetically sorted (e.g. anna is first in the expected output). Blank cells should be ignored.

The expected output is the data summarised in long format:


You can try this formula. Change the range in the Let function to accommodate your dataset (here listed as A:D based on the question).
=let(range,A:D,toprow,row(index(range,1,1)),data,arrayformula(split(transpose(split(textjoin(",",true,tocol(BYCOL(range,LAMBDA(bc,vstack("|"&filter(bc,row(bc)=toprow),sort(filter(bc,row(bc)>toprow),1,1)))),1,1)),"|")),",")),wraprows(torow(BYROW(data,LAMBDA(k,makearray(1,(COUNTA(k)-1)*2,lambda(r,c,if(isodd(c),index(k,r,1),(index(k,r,(c/2)+1))))))),1),2))


is there a way to do this based on a specific cell range only: F5:Q17. I tried replacing A:D

I used your feedback to improve the answer. It should now be agnostic to where your data is within the spreadsheet. The range of cells should be identified in the beginning of the let function.

lastly sorry, is there an easy way to do a version where the output is sorted across the whole of the second column (instead of sorted within group)

You can try this =let(range,F5:Q17,toprow,row(index(range,1,1)),data,arrayformula(split(transpose(split(textjoin(",",true,tocol(BYCOL(range,LAMBDA(bc,vstack("|"&filter(bc,row(bc)=toprow),sort(filter(bc,row(bc)>toprow),1,1)))),1,1)),"|")),",")),query(wraprows(torow(BYROW(data,LAMBDA(k,makearray(1,(COUNTA(k)-1)*2,lambda(r,c,if(isodd(c),index(k,r,1),(index(k,r,(c/2)+1))))))),1),2),"select Col1,Col2 order by Col2"))

Don't forget to mark answered!
